# Creating a list from conditionals during iteration

Tags: scheme

I have written a simple procedure to find the divisors of a number (not including the number itself). I have figured out how to print them, but I would like to have this function return a list containing each of the divisors.

```
(define (divisors n)

  (do ((i 1 (+ i 1)))    
    ((> i (floor (/ n 2))))
    (cond 
      ((= (modulo n i) 0)
       (printf "~a " i)))))
```

My idea is to create a local list, adding elements to it where my printf expression is, and then having the function return that list. How might I go about doing that? I am new to Scheme, and Lisp in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you necessarily have to use have to use [`do`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html?q=do#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmore-scheme..rkt%29._do%29%29)? here's a way:

```
(define (divisors n)
  (do ((i 1 (add1 i))
       (acc '() (if (zero? (modulo n i)) (cons i acc) acc)))
    ((> i (floor (/ n 2)))
     (reverse acc))))
```

But I believe it's easier to understand if you build an output list with a [named `let`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/let.html#%28part._.Named_let%29):

```
(define (divisors n)
  (let loop ((i 1))
    (cond ((> i (floor (/ n 2))) '())
          ((zero? (modulo n i))
           (cons i (loop (add1 i))))
          (else (loop (add1 i))))))
```

Or if you happen to be using Racket, you can use [`for/fold`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Ffold%29%29) like this:

```
(define (divisors n)
  (reverse
   (for/fold ([acc '()])
     ([i (in-range 1 (add1 (floor (/ n 2))))])
     (if (zero? (modulo n i))
         (cons i acc)
         acc))))
```

Notice that all of the above solutions are written in a functional programming style, which is the idiomatic way to program in Scheme - without using mutation operations. It's also possible to write a procedural style solution (see @GoZoner's answer), similar to how you'd solve this problem in a C-like language, but that's not idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a local variable `l` and extend it instead of printing stuff.  When done, return it.  Like this:

```
(define (divisors n)
  (let ((l '()))
    (do ((i 1 (+ i 1)))    
        ((> i (floor (/ n 2))))
      (cond ((= (modulo n i) 0)
             (set! l (cons i l))))
    l))
```

Note that because each `i` was 'consed' onto the front of `l`, the ordering in `l` will be high to low.  Use `(reverse l)` as the return value if low to high ordering is needed.